# Receive HTML MMS messages

Tags: browser, mms, stock-browser

### Background

I have recently switched to Android from iOS and have run into a problem regarding receiving MMS messages on the phone.

Previously on iPhone, I was able to receive HTML MMS messages by sending them base64 encoded with the following MIME headers:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64;
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="html.html";
```

These would come in as HTML files which would thus be interpreted by iOS's built in browser upon clicking them.

---

On Android, sending the same messages with the same identical MIME headers results in essential HTML code being stripped out such as the `<style>` tags around inline CSS and the like, yet header levels (`h1, h2, h3`) are appropriately headers within the message, and numerous other strange behaviors.

I should note that on Android, the message comes in clear text form (except for the strange headers thing and hyperlinks), almost not even interpreting the HTML and furthermore stripping out some tags.

This is the behavior in multiple messaging apps including the new Google Messenger app.

So, to sum up... Android:

1. Interprets the HTML code as plain text (for the most part)
2. Interprets headers and <strike>hyperlinks</strike> **(UPDATE: does not interpret hyperlinks)** within the mostly plain text results
3. Displays a limited amount of plain text

### Question

Is there a way to receive an HTML MMS message so that it can be interpreted in full by a browser on Android?